# Wordpress loop : how to exclude some posts with their status?

Tags: loop

I'm working on a website and I've made a loop that displays all posts even drafts. I would like to avoid this so I've set `'post_status' => 'publish'`, and it doesn't work. Can someone help me ?

```
 <?php

                global $actu_pageId;
                if (get_the_ID() == $actu_pageId) {
                    $posts = new WP_Query(array('post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 9));

                } else {
                    $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 9, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'category_name' => get_field('categorie')));
                }
                if ($posts->have_posts()) {

                    global $posts;
                    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
                        $posts->the_post();

                        get_template_part('template-parts/posts_archive');
                    }

                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code (the part with the loop, not the whole file)? `'post_status'=>'publish'` should work and is the default setting. Maybe a theme/plugin is manipulating this (usually via `pre_get_posts`)?

Comment: hello @kero, thank you for your answer. Maybe it's because of ACF ?

Comment: ACF shouldn't interfere. Can you disable all plugins, switch to the default theme and look if this still fails?

Comment: When I disable all plugins, the site doesn't load anymore, it only shows a blank page

Comment: @ferdi_ can you echo something in the else statement? Does that appear when you reload?

Answer (score 0):

You have the line `global $posts;` which is probably pulling a globalised $posts variable defined somewhere else and thus overwriting the one you just made. Remove that line or change the variable name to something unique.